# How to get all sortable columns from MatSort

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material2

I have data table and I want to apply the sorting process from the back-end side, so the end user can apply sorting on multiple columns, what I need to do is get all `columns` with their sorting values `asc/desc` on each `sortChange` event.

lets say the columns are:
 `name, gender, date_of_birth.`
results should be:

```
[
{'name', 'asc'},
{'gender', 'desc'},
{'date_of_birth', 'desc'},
]
```

ts code:

```
ngOnInit() {
 this.getData([])
 this.sort.sortChange.subscribe(
            () => {
            // access all the sortable columns
            let sortable_columns = -------------- // what should I write here?
            // call the http service
            this.getData(sortable_columns)
            });
}
```

Now I think that the general alogrithm is fine, but I can't find the right syntax to access the sortable columns, any Idea on how to do this? 
Thanks.

Comment: you can follow the following link   https://github.com/abdulk1/angular-6-datatable

this library have all sorting and pagination

Comment: check the example that they have for MatSort,
[link](https://material.angular.io/components/sort/examples)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by storing the active column (the most recently sorted MatSortable column) in a separated structure after each `SortCahnge`.

HTML Script:

```
<mat-table matSort #table [dataSource]="dataSource" (matSortChange)="sortData($event)">
</mat-table>
```

ts code:

```
    ngOnInit() {
            this.filterationArray['sort'] = [];
    }
    sortData(sort: Sort) {
        let index = this.filterationArray['sort'].findIndex(
            (elem) => {
                return elem[0] == sort.active;
            }
            );

        if (index == -1)
            this.filterationArray['sort'].push([sort.active, sort.direction]);
        else
            this.filterationArray['sort'][index][1] = sort.direction;

        console.log(this.filterationArray);
        // call the get service
        this.getDataFromBackEnd(this.filterationArray);
    }
```